# Como faço um programa em C gerar um binario executavel?

Tags: c, linux

Olá, queria saber como faço pra um programa em C gerar um outro binario executavel
eg: o binario elf x-elf.bin ao ser executado cria um outro binario executavel y-elf.bin

Comment: Esse outro binário executável criado seria uma cópia de si mesmo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode usar as funcoes standard C: `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fread` e `fclose` usando as flags `wb` para escrever ou `rb` para ler dados binarios.

> The mode string can also include the letter 'b' either as a last
>   character or  as  a  character between  the  characters in any of the
>   two-character strings described above.  This is strictly for
>   compatibility with C89 and has no effect; the 'b' is ignored on all
>   POSIX  conforming  sys‐tems,  including  Linux.  (Other systems may
>   treat text files and binary files differently, and adding the 'b' may
>   be a good idea if you do I/O to a binary file and expect that  your 
>   program may be ported to non-UNIX environments.)
>
> Fonte: man 3 fopen

Se voce estiver fazendo um programa somente para Linux simplesmente use um `fopen` com a flag `w` e escreva dentro do arquivo os dados binarios.

**Exemplo:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        /* Criando arquivo binario */

        int dados_binarios = 1;

        FILE *file = fopen ("arquivo.bin", "wb");

        if (file != NULL)
        {
            fwrite (&dados_binarios, sizeof (dados_binarios), 1, file);
            fclose (file);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

*Maiores informacoes digite `man 3 fopen` no teu terminal.*

Comment: no caso tenho que colocar o hexadecimal de um binario?

Comment: Exato, tu pode instalar um editor de arquivos binarios para abrir um arquivo e ver o conteudo, aconselho voce usar o `hexedit`, que pode ser facilmente instalado atraves do comando `apt install hexedit` se sua distribuicao for baseada no Debian (Ubuntu). Depois e so digitar no teu terminal `hexedit <nome do arquivo>`.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, conseguiu esclarecer tudo q eu queria (y)

Comment: Tranquilo, se respondi tua pergunta nao esquece de marcar a pergunta como respondida. Valeu!